# How to join these 2 mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 kind-of complex queries that I wish to be able to join, but not quite sure the syntax to do it.

Query 1:

```
select month(Date_1) as Date_1, 
       sum(number_1) as number_1 
  from table_1 
  where Date_1 between '2012-01-01' and '2013-01-01' 
  group by month(Date_1);
```

which gives this result:

[image]

Query 2:

```
select count(distinct number_2) as number_2, 
       month(Date_2) as Date_2 
  from table_2 
  where Date_2 between '2012-01-01' and '2013-01-01' 
  group by month(Date_2) 
  order by month(Date_2) desc;
```

which gives this result:

[image]

I want to join these 2 queries so that the number_1 is matched up with number_2 for when Date_1 and Date_2 columns are equal.  One row per month.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want both numbers in one rows, along with their matching date, like 1   964789.36    137  ?

Comment: Yes that is what I want, the answer below solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T1.Date_1, T1.number_1, T2.number_2 from 

(select month(Date_1) as Date_1, 
       sum(number_1) as number_1 
  from table_1 
  where Date_1 between '2012-01-01' and '2013-01-01' 
  group by month(Date_1))T1

inner join

(select count(distinct number_2) as number_2, 
       month(Date_2) as Date_2 
  from table_2 
  where Date_2 between '2012-01-01' and '2013-01-01' 
  group by month(Date_2) 
  order by month(Date_2) desc)T2

on T1.Date_1 = T2.Date_2;
```

Esentially, joining the two temporary tables (formed as a result of queries) on the month.